# Why wont the nude.js html5canvas demo work locally?

Tags: javascript, html, nude.js

Try this nice JavaScript: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/demo/
<sub>**Warning:** slightly NSFW.</sub>

It won't work when i open it from my local machine. Either by copying the 3 exact source codes and making the picture locations absolute (or else by downloading https://github.com/pa7/nude.js/archive/master.zip).

I am lost why? it must be a silly/simple reason since [the demo page](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/demo/) is obviously working and JavaScript only, so why would it make a difference where you store it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried debugging with the console?

Comment: Hope you don't mind the NSFW warning...just trying to spare someone an embarrassing conversation with their HR department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because of the browser security restrictions. are you opening the html file from the file system, instead of serving it from localhost? or are you referencing resources from another domain that does not have CORS enabled? Debugging with the console should help.